# For or While loop with 2 max variables, one of which being an array (Programming I)

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following assignment for my Programming I class:

> Prompt for the price of each item.  Store each item price in the array named prices.  When the user has reached $1,000 or 5 items, 
>   print out how much was spent, how many items were bought, how much is left, and the average price.
>   Print a table of the prices of the items bought.

My original attempt got very mangled:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int cost = 1;
    int total = 0;
    int i = 0;
    const int MAXNUM = 5;
    int prices[MAXNUM];


    while (total < 1000 && cost !=0 && i < MAXNUM)
    {
        for (int x = 0; i < MAXNUM; i++)
        {
            cout << "Please enter the price of the item you are purchasing:"<< endl << i+1 << "." <<"$";
            cin >> cost;
            total+=cost;
        }
//          total += cost;
    }
/*  


//      cout << \n << "Name: ";
//      cin >> name;
    } */
    cout << "You spent $" << total << " by purchasing " << /* **************** << */ " items, you have $" << 1000-total <</* " leftover, and your average price was $" <<  total/ ******** << */ "." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So I started over from scratch and so far I have this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  const int NUMELS = 5;

  int i, prices[NUMELS];
  string items [NUMELS];

  for (i = 0; i < NUMELS; i++)   
  {
    cout << "Enter the name of the product: ";
    cin  >> items[i];
    cout << "Enter the price of the product: $";
    cin  >> prices[i];
  }
  cout << endl;
  for (i = 0; i < NUMELS; i++)    
      cout << items[i]<< " cost you $"<< prices[i]<< endl;

  return 0;
}
```

My biggest difficulty right now is trying to have the program check so that the price doesn't go over $1000 (Which I've written a program for in the past) while ALSO checking to make sure the user purchases no more than 5 items.  There are more steps after all of this but once I figure out the base I should be able to build the rest on my own.

I tried putting       if (acc > 1000) 
        break;  at the end of my for loop, but then [this happened...](https://i.gyazo.com/4b05b24c6c2aa70a51534448528a8c65.png)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: SO doesn't like assignment questions.

Comment: you didnt ask a question. SO also doesn't like links as the only hint to what is the problem

Comment: Your output should not loop till `NUMELS` in the case that `acc > 1000`

Comment: SO also doesn't like text as images, because they're not searchable...

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt using `break` was not a bad idea, but the loop that prints the result should use the amount of elements entered , not the fixed value 5.

```
int main()
{
  const int NUMELS = 5;

  int TotalPrice = 0;
  int i, j, prices[NUMELS];
  string items [NUMELS];

  for (i = 0; i < NUMELS; i++)   
  {
      if (TotalPrice >= 1000)
          break;

      cout << "Enter the name of the product: ";
      cin  >> items[i];
      cout << "Enter the price of the product: $";
      cin  >> prices[i];

      TotalPrice += prices[i];
  }
  cout << endl;
  for (j = 0; j < i; j++)    
      cout << items[j]<< " cost you $"<< prices[j]<< endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This `break`s **on** £1000, not just when over.

Comment: @underscore_d : True, The assignment at the top of the OP states `When the user has reached $1,000 or 5 items`. To me that means 1000 and over.

Comment: Ah - good point. I was looking at their paraphrasing of that at the bottom, so I guess _they_'re the one who misunderstood ;-)

Answer (score 1):

if I get you, you'll like to also check if the user has exceeded $1000 in the loop that checks if user has bought 5 item. If that is, maybe this should work.

```
for (int i = 0, exceed = 0; i < NUMELS && exceed < 1000; i++){
    cout << "Enter the name of the product: ";
    cin  >> items[i];
    cout << "Enter the price of the product: $";
    cin  >> prices[i];

    exceed += prices[i];
}
```

Try this

Comment: I guess I was too slow with... without surprise I have same answer as the above

Comment: The comma operator only returns the value of its final input expression, so this never checks/cares whether `i < NUMELS`. Perhaps you can think of another way to do this...

Comment: thanks for that... just edited @underscore_d

Comment: Cool, now this is arguably a more tidy way to do it than the others! We could probably even move the final increment to the `for` declarator: `; exceed += prices[i], i++`... or even `exceed += prices[i++]`. However, people's opinions tend to vary on whether they find this more or less readable. **edit** however, like the other answer, it breaks **on** £1000, not just when over.

Comment: [cont] ...which is correct if we read the assignment rather than the OP's interpretation thereof, haha, oops.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
while(){}
```

cycle

write something like this

```
  int count = 0, sum = 0;
  while(count  < 5 && sum <= 1000)  
  {
    cout << "Enter the name of the product: ";
    cin  >> items[count ];
    cout << "Enter the price of the product: $";
    cin  >> prices[count ];
    sum += prices[count ];
    count++;
  }
  cout << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)    
    cout << items[i]<< " cost you $"<< prices[i]<< endl;
```

Comment: [sorry, i got this the wrong way around before] This will not break if the price reaches _exactly_ 1000, which is what the original assignment stipulated (although the OP made the same mistake)

Comment: well, just change "<=" to "<", and thats it